# new pop up window (Qt4 / PyQt4, Python3)

Tags: python, qt4, python-3.x, pyqt4

It must be something very simple, but I didn't manage to find a way...
I have a GUI with `MainWindow (QMainWindow)`, where I added Help menu and `actionAbout QAction` via Qt Designer. Now I want a small new window with text "Program... Version... etc" to show up when I press About item in Help menu.

A `triggered` signal seem to work and I get `NotImplementedError` when I press on About. But no idea how to show a new window now from this signal...

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    My main GUI window
    """
    def __init__(self, db, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
...
    @pyqtSlot(QAction)
    def on_menuAbout_triggered(self, action):
        """
        Slot documentation goes here.
        """
        # TODO: not implemented yet
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was indeed easy:

```
@pyqtSlot(QAction)
def on_menuAbout_triggered(self, action):
    """
    Show about page
    """
    about_box = QMessageBox(self)
    about_box.about(self, 'About', 'This is a GUI...\n\n<a href="www.google.com">www.google.com</a>')
#        about_box.setText('This is a GUI')
#        about_box.exec()
```

What remains is to insert a link to the page (here google just as an example). The example above is not working. Any ideas how to make a link out the text?